# Visualizing models, data, and training with tensorboard in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

Following [this Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_tutorial.html) 
to visualize images in tensorboard using torch.utils.tensorboard got error

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter('runs/fashion_mnist_experiment_1')
writer.add_embedding(features,
                metadata=class_labels,
                label_img=images.unsqueeze(1))
writer.close()
```

Error:

```
        AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.io.gfile' has no attribute 'get_filesystem'
```

Comment: I suggest that you fine help on the official github issues and add a comment to this post so that the developers know more people are affected: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/30966

Comment: Since you've asked "Visualizing models", you can see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/72526515/6117565

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
writer = SummaryWriter(path)
img_grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(torch.FloatTensor(imgs)) #imgs represent a batch of images with shape BxCxHxW
writer_add_image('images', img_grid)
```

source : https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_tutorial.html#writing-to-tensorboard